Unity 2D isometric sorting algorythm
I am looking for a solution to properly sort objects on an isometeric scene in my 2D game

Currently I am using such approach:
int itemSortingOrder = - (int) (item.GameObject.transform.parent.transform.position.y * 1000);
But the probklem is that transform.position is stored as WorldCoordinates

That is lead to an issue when several walls around a single cell have the same coordinates.
I had solve this issue by calculating not only position of the item, but add "bounds" of the object:

But I feel that I had chose a wrong approach and this should be solve somehow otherway.
Could you give some advice to an approach of sorting objects on the scene?
